# Deflecting an ion moving at a relativistic velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, forces

Given an ion of mass $m$ moving at a relativistic velocity $v_1$ as shown in the figure.  A force $F$ that is perpendicular to the ion's direction of travel deflects it a very small angle $\theta$ and accelerates the ion to a new total (vertical and horizontal) velocity $v_2$. $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor, and $\rho$ is the relativistic momentum.

[image: Ion Geometry]

How should the angle $\theta$ be calculated?

In solution (1), the ion's vertical velocity is unchanged.  In solution (2), the ion's momentum on the vertical axis is conserved: $$p_1 = p_2  \cos\theta$$

The angle $\theta$ is very small, so the force can be assumed to act on the ion tangentially. I think the angle should be calculated using (2) to conserve momentum on the vertical axis -- however doesn't this apply a vertical force on the ion to slow it down since $\theta$ is larger than the value calculated by (1)?  Given $v_2$, a larger $\theta$ implies a smaller vertical velocity component for $v_2$.  Both solutions converge in the non-relativistic case.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In relativity, a force can and does change the perpendicular components of the (3-) velocity of a particle. You can slow down a particle along one direction without applying a force along that direction.

How do we know? Imagine a particle traveling very close tor the speed of light along the $x$-axis with momentum $\rho_x$. If we gave it some momentum in the $y$-direction $\rho_y=\rho_x$, it should travel at a 45 degree angle from the $x$-axis.

If the $x$-velocity remains at near the speed of light, then the total velocity would be $\sqrt{2}$ times that, which can be more than the speed of light. That would be a problem, so you know the $x$-velocity cannot stay the same, it must decrease.

Also, I think the problem has a typo; it should be $\cos\theta$ not $\sin\theta$?

Comment: Agree; and corrected.  Thanks

Comment: This also implies you can increase the ion's vertical velocity through reciprocity.  If you start at the bottom, when the ion is moving at v2 and apply the force in the opposite direction to the original force -- its vertical velocity would increase to keep its vertical momentum constant.  Which makes sense.